# How can I generate new metadata for a search query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js13

I have a search page that utilizes a search API using OpenAI. I want to change the meta description for the page to be 'Search | %s', with %s being the decoded search query. However, in Nextjs 13 we can't put in useSearchParams in async functions. Has anybody else been able to overcome this challenge or implemented search before in Nextjs 13?

The code below is what I had, and I don't know how to refactor it because the documentation is limited.

```
"use client";

import { Metadata } from "next";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

type Props = {
  searchParams: { [q: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
};

// http://localhost:3000/search?q=How+can+I+create+a+web+app%3F

export async function generateMetadata({
  searchParams,
}: Props): Promise<Metadata> {
  const [originalQuestion, setOriginalQuestion] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();
    const searchQuery = searchParams ? searchParams.get("q") : null;
    const encodedSearchQuery = encodeURI(searchQuery || "");
    const decodedSearchQuery = decodeURI(encodedSearchQuery);
    setOriginalQuestion(decodedSearchQuery);
  }, []);

  return {
    description: `Search CodingOH: ${originalQuestion}`,
  };
}

export default function PageLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I initially tried to use useRouter, but it is unable to be placed in the generateMetadata function.  Then, I tried placing the tag in the html return, but it did not render. Now, I am trying to use useSearchParams, but I am going nowhere with it.

Answer (score 1):

A problem with your code is `use client`. Nextjs does not call `generateMetadata` for Client components.

A possible solution to include the search value in the metadata is setting a query parameter in a Client component, which can be accessed as `searchParams` in the Server component.

```
# /app/search/page.tsx
import SearchInput from "./search";

export async function generateMetadata({ searchParams }) {
    return {
        description: `Search: ${JSON.stringify(searchParams)}`,
      };
}

export default function SearchPage({ searchParams, children}) {
    return(
        <div>
            <div>{JSON.stringify(searchParams)}</div>
            <SearchInput/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
# /app/search/search.tsx
'use client'

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { usePathname, useSearchParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function SearchInput() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<string>('')
    const pathname = usePathname()
    const router = useRouter();
    const queryParams = useSearchParams()

    useEffect(() => {
        let url = pathname || '/';
        const urlSearchParams = queryParams ? new URLSearchParams(queryParams) : new URLSearchParams();
        urlSearchParams.set('search', value);
        if (urlSearchParams.size > 0) {
            url += '?' + urlSearchParams.toString();
        }        router.replace(url, { scroll: false });
    }, [value])

    const changeHandler = (event: any) => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
    }

    return(<input onChange={changeHandler} value={value}/>)
}
```

Comment: I see. Would I put this snippet in my app/search/page.tsx or app/search/layout.tsx? Also, exactly how is this inserting the content of the query into the metadata, specifically the title.

Comment: I have tried to pass your snippet in my page.jsx, but in layout.jsx not receive searchParams value. Can you give me a full code example. Thanks

Comment: @zos, I have updated with complete code. In case you want to use this in a layout you probable need to change it from `searchParams` to `Params` in a `[....search]` folder.

Comment: @nordic70 thanks for your support but it don't work

Comment: @zos, hereby a link to my demo https://github.com/nordicgit70/nextjs-app/tree/v0.0.1. This solution works with searchParams. Just clone the repo and try it yourself.

Comment: @zos, did you have a look at the repo? Can you confirm that the solution works?